# Rendering two charts doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, charts, zingchart

I use ZingCharts library and I have two charts in different .js files and each of them has its own render, I add them in html in this order

`<script src="customGraph.js"></script>
 <script src="mainGraph.js"></script>`

and the first graph doesn't show, I reversed them and it happens the same, the first one (in the html file) doesn't show. I also put them as

```
<div id='custom'></div>
<div id='main'></div>
```

I don't know what is the problem, if any of you have experienced someting similar, please help.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like it may be an issue with how you are loading zingchart or your script files. Can you replicate your issue in something like https://plnkr.co for us to see?

Comment: @mike-schultz The problem was exactly that.. the loading, I put it in same window.onload and it went fine :)